# chainerのサンプルコード実装

Tags: python

chainerのサイトにある[サンプルコード](https://github.com/pfnet/chainer/blob/master/examples/mnist/train_mnist.py)を実行したところ

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

が表示され、

```
train mean loss=inf, accuracy=0.423949999753
test  mean loss=inf, accuracy=0.555500000119
epoch 2
train mean loss=inf, accuracy=0.418599997945
test  mean loss=inf, accuracy=0.520499998331
epoch 3
train mean loss=inf, accuracy=0.468833331193
test  mean loss=inf, accuracy=0.556299994588
```

このようにloss関数が、infになってしまいます。

どの情報を見ても、サンプルコードを実行した結果このようになったケースはなく 解決法が分かりません。

環境は、

python2.7.10
chainer1.5.0.3
OS mac ELcapitan
プロセッサ 1.7 GHz Intel Core i7
メモリ 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
です。

PCのスペックの問題なのでしょうか。 回答を宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: GPU(CUDA)は使っていますか？それともCPU単体？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
CPU単体で動かした時の結果です。